# CheckBoxList with a scrollbar

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I know this would normally be an easy solution but in my case the situation may be a little different. I am making a control with C# client side code. This is included in a search panel. Everything I read says normally I could just wrap the CheckBoxList within a DIV tag. However, My search field automatically creates the table based upon what selectors I need. This is in a table format. You cannot have a div within a table. Is there anyway to override that table cell to allow scrolling? What are your suggestions?

I tried wrapping the checkboxlist in a div and limiting the height of the DIV and setting the overflow to auto and then scroll. First off, the scroll bars arent showing. This is because the checkboxlist still extends the table cell to fit the whole box.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered checking out the `overflow` CSS property and setting it to `scroll` ?

Comment: I added that CSS property to the cell. it shows a greyed out scroll bar. However, How can I limit the height of the TD ? I set the overflow to scroll. I just need to lock that particular <td> to a particular height. Right now the TD renders all of the options.